# Scraping data from HTML to return to cells in Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am very new to coding. I know the basics, but I don't need that advanced of knowledge for my field--aside from this project.

I am attempting to search a license number on the AZ Medical Board website, click the search result to pull up a profile, and transfer the information on a profile to cells in Excel.

So far my code looks like this and it works perfectly (aside from the data scraping part)

```
Sub AZMDSearch()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim Name2 As Object

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://gls.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/public/WebVerificationSearch.aspx"

Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
Wend
'**********************************************************************
With IE.document
delay 1
.getelementbyid("tbFileNumber").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
delay 1
.getelementbyid("btnLicense").Click
delay 2
.getelementsbytagname("a")(0).Click
End With
'**********************************************************************
```

The code does exactly what I want it to do up until this point.

Now, here's what the HTML looks like for the data I want to transfer over:

```
<span id="dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnEntName"><b>Gabby Laub 
MD</b><br /></span>
<span id="dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnPracAddr"><br />1234 S Pine<br 
/>Scottsdale AZ 85258<br />Phone: (123) 456-7891<br /></span>
```

I need to be able to pull the Name (Gabby Laub) into Cell(i,2), the address part 1 (1234 s Pine) into Cell(i,3), address part 2 (Scottsdale, AZ) into Cell(i,4), and phone number into Cell(i,5).

I was working on something like this:

```
Set Name = IE.document.getelementbyid("dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnEntName").innerHTML
```

But it doesn't work at all. I have been working on this project for weeks, and I would really appreciate some help. Obviously I'm aware that I am missing Next i and End sub.

Again, the ONLY part I need help on is how to actually get the data into Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
Cells(i, 2).Value = IE.document.getelementbyid("dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnEntName").getelementsbytagname("b").innerText

Cells(i, 3).Value = IE.document.getelementbyid("dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnPracAddr").innerText
```

Since address1, address2 and phone would all be in Cells(i, 3) you might want to use to use text to column to split them into their appropriate columns.

Additionally you could create an array to store these data in if you're doing a bigger search. Then you could paste the array values into their cells after you've finished scraping, like:

```
searchInfo(i, 1) = IE.document.getelementbyid("dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnEntName").getelementsbytagname("b").innerText
searchInfo(i, 2) = IE.document.getelementbyid("dtgGeneral_ctl02_lblLeftColumnPracAddr").innerText
```

Then after looping:

```
 For i = 1 to last row
       Cells(i,2).Value = searchInfo(i, 1)   
       Cells(i,3).Value = searchInfo(i, 2)
 Next i
```

You'd still have the text to column issue but that can be solved pretty easily with some code in the loop. Specifics just depend on how the third column's values come out.

EDIT: Based on your comments below, this worked for me. It might take a little customizing, but this is the idea.

```
    ' remove .getelementsbytagname("a")(0).Click and replace with this  
.location = .getElementsByTagName("a").getAttributes("href")
```

Comment: Every time I try anything like what you suggested I get an "object required" error.

Comment: Ahhh I think I discovered the issue. The .getelementsbytagname("a")(0).Click pulls up a separate tab, so VBA is searching for thr id in the wrong tab/HTML. Does anyone know how to fix this?